# CSS file considered as being an image resource

Tags: html, css, http, mime-types

I am not sure what the problem is, but the css stylesheet appears under the images group when I inspect my web page with safari or chrome, and shows that the "Resource Type" is image, even when the MIME type is correct and shows "text/css".

**SS of the problem:** [image]

Line of html that links the css file to the html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

In addition to the built-in inspector not displaying the type correctly, this poses an additional problem of not displaying the contents of the file, and displaying an unknown image icon instead.

I honestly don't have the slightest clue as to where to start looking, or what to google to find out what the problem is. Is there more to determining types of files than the extension and/or the MIME type??

EDIT:

CSS with `url()` was causing the problem.

```
background-image: url();
```

Apparently the usage of url without anything in the brackets causes this to happen. Can you enlighten me on why this might happen??

Comment: Have you got any .htaccess file you didn't write by yourself or that you are not sure about ? Could you add the CSS' HTML declaration to your question ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet No .htaccess files I didn't write :/  There is one for a simple user/pass authentication, but nothing that would cause the resource type to change. Plus, this happens when I view the page on my local machine, without apache.

I also added the html declaration that links the css file.

Comment: Can you give us the CSS code, but only the lines using `url` in it ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet I was looking for instances of `url` in my css, and found a line with just `url()` in it. Thanks for pointing me in that direction! Do you know why this happens by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you leave an `url()` call as blank in the style of an element, it will send a request using the relative path, to get an image corresponding to the base URL itself.

To simplify, in that case, you asked style.css to loads itself as an image, that's why it resulted as your style.css file to be considered as an image. Tell me if I'm clear enough.

Just be sure to never leave your `url()` calls as blank and remember that the path is relative to the stylesheet path.

Comment: Ah, so it would load it first as a text file, then load it a second time as an image (am I understanding correctly?)

Comment: Pretty much yeah, and the result will depends on the browsers : One will apply the styles, while another will ignore everything, ...